# How can i get specific product in magento?

Tags: magento

i want to get latest 3 project and in this first two product should be skip. I am explaining this suppose i have a array a[]=(0,1,2,3,4,5).
Now i want to get a array in which there are only three item(2,3,4).
How can i do this in magento.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the way to do it in Magento.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC') //Order by product id(most recient)
->getSelect()
    ->limit(10,2); //This will return up to 10 products skiping the first 2.


//Now do what you want with it.
foreach($collection as $product){
    echo $product->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the product IDs with the first two elements in the original array removed and
//only the next 3 after that
$product_ids = array_slice($a, 2, 3); //$a is the array you mentioned in your post

//create an array to store the products
$products = array();

//loop through the product IDs and load the actual Product model
foreach($product_ids as $pid) {
    $products[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
}
```

Going with your example, after this, `$products` will contain the Products with IDs 2, 3, and 4.

Answer (score -1):

there are different ways to do that.
I give you two solutions. I hope I understand your question.

```
<?php
...
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$items = $collection->getItems();// You get all activated products of your catalog
$newItems = array_splice($items, 2); // You remove the first two elements of the array
....
?>
```

The second solution is to filter your collection to get only a limited number of selected products which is better because you don't load everything, you load only what you need.

```
<?php
...
/* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where ('entity_id IN (?)', array(0,1,2,3,4,5))
    ->limit(5,2); // You get 5 products up to the 2 result (offset). You can remove this line if you slice your array before to give it in the where clause.

$items = $collection->getItems();
....
?>
```

Comment: Not working any solution.When i use limit function it gives me a error of call undefined function.And in first solution when i use array_splice function whole array become 0

Comment: Both work, I check again after your comment. 
- Did you correctly copy and paste the code? - Did you correctly adapt to your situation? - What Magento do you use?
I did the test on Magento 1.5.1
The method "limit" is a method of Zend_Db_Select which comes from the getSelect of the collection.
Provide a context maybe it's different in your situation. You provide no context.